# I am getting an error which says lowercase_lines is not defined

Tags: python

```
import string

def getData(filename):
  with open(filename,'r') as f:
    lines=[line.rstrip() for line in f]
    lines=[x.lower() for x in lines]
    return lines
filename="bibleSentences.txt"
getData(filename)

def normalize(filename):
    lowercase_lines=[x.lower() for x in getData(filename)]
    return lowercase_lines  
normalize(filename)

def replace_all(text,dic):
  for p in normalize(filename):
    for i,j in dic.iteritems():
      text=text.replace(i,j)
  print (text)
  return text
text=lowercase_lines
dic={"and":"","the" :"", "in":"", "it":"", "was":"", "his":"", "of":"", "so":"" }
print(replace_all(normalize))
```

Comment: It is local to the normalize function. You can't access it directly outside the function. You are calling normalize but then discarding the return value - save it in that variable. (Hopefully the syntax will be obvious - i can't easily post any code just now as writing this on a phone.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `lowercase_lines` is a local variable to the `normalize` function, which you are calling without saving its return to a variable.

Just put `lowercase_lines = normalize(filename)`

Answer (score 0):

The only place `lowercase_lines` is defined is in this function:

```
def normalize(filename):
    lowercase_lines=[x.lower() for x in getData(filename)]
    return lowercase_lines
```

But that variable is in what's called "function scope", which means it only exists until that function exists.  You need to capture the value being returned from the function so that you can use it outside the function.  But you are actually doing that in the line:

```
for p in normalize(filename):
```

I don't see what value the line:

```
text=lowercase_lines
```

has for you.  You are already using the result of the normalize() function above that.  I think removing that line is what you want to do, unless there is other code further down that uses the value `text`.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are all returning values but you need to set them to a variable:

```
lines = getData(filename)

lowercase_lines = normalize(filename)
```

etc.